# Sorting multiple models on same controller

Tags: ember.js

Is there any way to sort multiple models set on the same controller via the `RSVP.hash` by different `sortProperties`?

Here is the route code:

```
Application.SomeIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      foos: this.store.find('foo'),
      bars: this.store.find('bar')
    });
  }
});
```

How do I sort `foos` and `bars` in my `SomeIndexController`? Is there any way to sort models by different `sortProperties`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows:

```
Application.SomeIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      foos: this.store.find('foo'),
      bars: this.store.find('bar')
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, modelHash) {
    controller.set('foos', modelHash.foos);
    controller.set('bars', modelHash.bars);
  }
});

Application.SomeIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  sortedFoos: Ember.computed.sort('foos', 'foosSorting'),
  sortedBars: Ember.computed.sort('bars', 'barsSorting'),
  // Sorting properties
  foosSorting: ['propA'],
  barsSorting: ['propB'],
});
```

I hope this answers your question.